# Vue3 Unit Testing: [Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function

Tags: vue.js, mocha.js

I have a Vue3 project created with the VueCLI. Executing unit tests fails for mounted components. It says `[Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function.` The test file below complains about the made assertion: `AssertionError: expected '' to include 'Test'` on the Test.vue component. The first specified test works. What could be the issue? Which dependency versions and config files are needed in order to find the issue? I wanted to avoid to paste all of them to keep a better overview. I am using **mocha** and **chai**. Thanks!

[image: example.spec.ts]

[image: Test.vue]

Comment: I simply switched to JEST and everything works right on from the very beginning. Maybe some issue with Mocha & Chai? Even a newly created project (with vue-cli) isn't able to execute demo unit test which were created by vue-cli.

Comment: Dear Peter, please post the code not just place the screenshots in your question as whoever might want to help can't just copy & paste it to provide a solution. Make it as easy to potential helpers as you can.

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback @Hexodus! I will prepare the code once I face the same issue again. Thanks again!